# Check String Contains Only &nbsp; and &amp; only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string and i need to check only this string contains only `&nbsp;` & `&amp;`

### String

```
string oldStr ="&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;";
```

I have tried like this.

```
bool x = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldStr);
```

Comment: What is that? It looks like double encoded something. You'd first need to run it through whatever decoder twice to produce the actual string required and then do something on *that*.

Comment: Should your test string fail because it has spaces as well as &amp; and &nbsp;

Comment: @TechGuy the file is *definitely* double-encoded. `&nbsp;` isn't a space, it's 6 characters. In an HTML encoded string that's the encoding for a space. `&amp;` the encoding for `&`. Looks like someone encoded encoded the string twice, converting `&nbsp;` to `&amp;nbsp;`. You'll have to decode that string *twice* to get the original

Comment: Well, if that string is **not** double-encoded, then your code works perfectly. It does not consist of spaces (breaking or not), but has a lot of different other characters in it, for example ampersands and semicolons and characters. So you get `false`. Seems legit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your string is HTML which has been HTML encoded, you need to HTML decode it **twice**.

```
string oldStr = "&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;";

var result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(oldStr));

Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result));
```

This will output `true` (since a non-breaking space is whitespace).